# Varargs with inheritance in Java

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, variadic-functions, member-hiding

Suppose I have a class `Foo` like so:

```
public class Foo<T> {
    protected T invoke(Object... args);
}
```

Now suppose I add this:

```
public class Bar<T, Arg> extends Foo<T> {
    public T invoke(Arg arg);
}
```

Does this mean that I cannot create a `Bar<T, Object[]>` since it would create two `invoke()` methods with "essentially" the same signature?  Or would `Bar.invoke()` safely hide `Foo.invoke()` in this case (as `Bar.invoke()` is, runtime-wise, taking `Object` rather than the `Object[]` of `Foo.invoke()`)?

Related to this: is forwarding `Bar.invoke()` to `Foo.invoke()` safe and fine?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? This looks harder than any SCJP question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Bar.invoke` does not override `Foo.invoke`. If you call just `bar.invoke` with no arguments you'll get the `foo.invoke` called.

But you'll get a compile time error (`reference to invoke is ambiguous`) if you construct a `Bar` object: `Bar<Object, Object[]> bar = new Bar<Object, Object[]>()` and then invoke `bar.invoke(new Object[]{})` because the 2 invoke methods have the same erasure at runtime.